# My layout eats the last image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout for my row in a listview... last image is not displayed... why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/title"         
                android:textSize="14sp"         
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"        
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/description"   
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_weight="0"  
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>      


            <TextView android:id="@+id/variable" 
                android:textSize="12sp"      
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"        
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_weight="0"  
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:src="@drawable/disclosure"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance,

regards

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Yes sure ^^ here's the landscape version http://www.flickr.com/photos/4ndreast4gi/5927765022/ and here the normal http://www.flickr.com/photos/4ndreast4gi/5927764880/

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to specify that the layout is related to the row of the listview... I provided a screenshot of the whole screen, sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Try using a relativelayout so you don't have to have a linearlayout in the middle. I also have a three columnish thing going on so it should be similar for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  android:id ="@+id/container"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="62dp" 
  android:cacheColorHint="#ff000000" 
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:clickable="true"
  >
  <ImageView
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
  <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_alignTop = "@id/thumbnail"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/merchant"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:ellipsize="end" 
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:lines="1" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distance"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/merchant"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/priceButton"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/priceButton"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hmm, I have something similar to this in one of my projects, but I used a relativelayout for the listview rows. I would suggest you trying to use that as well because then you can specify that the image on the right is aligned to the parent's right and that the linearlayout in the middle is aligned to the parent's center.

Answer (score 0):

With no screenshot I would imagine you just have too much data on the screen , use a `scrollview` to allow the user to scroll.

Also why is your root layout's height limited to 70? Why dont you use `fill_parent` or `match_parent`

Comment: nothing changes sorry :( I can see last image only in landscape mode then the textviews contents are not so long..